# Форматирование данных в Angular 4

Tags: angular4, pipes

Я вывожу данные с БД в DateGrid. При этом форматирую их следующим образом:

```
export class VendorFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: IVendor[], filter: string): IVendor[] {
        filter = filter ? filter.toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
        return filter ? value.filter((app: IVendor) =>
            app.Title != null && app.Title.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1
            || app.Description != null && app.Description.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1
            || app.TestQuantity != null 
            || app.IsActive != null
             ) : value;
    }

}
```

IsActive имеет тип boolean, нужно при выводе превращать его в строку "Active" или "No Active". Как это прописать?

Comment: Куда данные выводишь?

Comment: Создавать отдельный `pipe`. Потому что у вас `pipe` занимается фильтрацией, а фильтрация не должна менять данные. Создайте другой `pipe` и в нем уже возвращайте нужную вам строчку.